# Looking to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\cot^{-1}(x)\ln^2(1+x^{-2})dx$

Tags: calculus

Given that,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\cot^{-1}(x)\ln(1+x^{-2})\mathrm dx=\pi\tag1$$

How can I find the closed form for (if it has a simple closed form) 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\cot^{-1}(x)\ln^2(1+x^{-2})\mathrm dx=3.54263...\tag2$$

Enforcing $y=\tan y$

$$2\int_{-\pi/4}^{+\pi/4}y\tan^{-1}(y)\ln(\csc y)\mathrm dx$$

Comment: By using the same techniques that allowed you to derive $(1)$, presumably integration of Binet's formula for $\log\Gamma$. The (enforcing *random substitution*) part is irrelevant and the context of this question is pretty poor.